# Google + Sign in API returning undefined when email requested

Tags: javascript, html, google-api, google-plus

I have just started developing a service which requires me adding a google plus sign in button, in order to return their email.

My code displays the sign-in button, and allows me to determine whether or not the sign in was successful. Unfortunately, when I try to log the users email to console it just returns undefined.

My code is below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      (function() {
       var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
       po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/client:plusone.js';
       var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
     })();
    </script>


<meta name="google-signin-clientid" content="264772654193-459t27quaqpc01hm7ok2fa0n677oul7c.apps.googleusercontent.com" />
<meta name="google-signin-scope" content="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login" />
<meta name="google-signin-requestvisibleactions" content="http://schema.org/AddAction" />
<meta name="google-signin-cookiepolicy" content="single_host_origin" />
<script type="text/javascript">
 (function() {
   var po = document.createElement('script');
   po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
   po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/client:plusone.js?onload=render';
   var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
   s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
 })();

   /* Executed when the APIs finish loading */
 function render() {

   // Additional params including the callback, the rest of the params will
   // come from the page-level configuration.
   var additionalParams = {
     'callback': signinCallback
   };

   // Attach a click listener to a button to trigger the flow.
   var signinButton = document.getElementById('signinButton');
   signinButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
     gapi.auth.signIn(additionalParams); // Will use page level configuration
   });
 }

function signinCallback(authResult) {
  if (authResult['status']['signed_in']) {
    document.getElementById('signinButton').setAttribute('style', 'display: none');
    getemail();
  } else {
    console.log('Sign-in state: ' + authResult['error']);
  }
}
function getemail(){
gapi.client.load('oauth2', 'v2', function() {
  gapi.client.oauth2.userinfo.get().execute(function(resp) {
    // Shows user email
    console.log(resp.email);
  })
});
}

</script>
<button id="signinButton">Sign in with Google</button>
```

Comment: userinfo endpoints are [deprecated](https://developers.google.com/+/api/auth-migration), don't use them anymore.